# Bootstrap and flexbox - collapse three `.col-md-3` into single columns on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and flexbox. I've got flexbox working on a 3 column (3 `.col-md-3` inside a `.container-fluid`) working.

But I want to collapse the columns (each `.col-md-3`) into single columns on mobile.

How can I do this? My markup is as follows:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row flex text-center">

            <div class="col-md-3 software-box-outer">
               <h1>
               Testing 1
               </h1>
            </div>

             <div class="col-md-3 software-box-outer">
               <h1>
               Testing 2
               </h1>
            </div>

             <div class="col-md-3 software-box-outer">
               <h1>
               Testing 3
               </h1>
            </div>

        </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
}

.row.flex:before,
.row.flex:after {
     display: none;
}

.software-box-outer {
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid grey;
}
```

Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/xpufcsuk/

I tried adding `.col-xs-12` to each `.col-md-3` hoping this would make it go into full single columns (occupy all 12 cols) on mobile. But it doesn't.

Comment: To use flex, you may use bootsrap 4 and its specific responsive class https://jsfiddle.net/xpufcsuk/1/   https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/

Comment: Ok, but I'm using Bootstrap 3.

Comment: I saw that, but you overwrite it with flex :) which is built-in in boostrap-4 . just wondering ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `flexbox` to work on only large deceives, you can use [`media queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Write you code into `@media screen and (min-width:767px)`, so it will work only when `device width > 767px`

```css
@media screen and (min-width:767px) {
  .flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .row.flex:before,
  .row.flex:after {
    display: none;
  }
}

.software-box-outer {
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row flex text-center">

    <div class="col-md-3 software-box-outer">
      <h1>
        Testing 1
      </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 software-box-outer">
      <h1>
        Testing 2
      </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 software-box-outer">
      <h1>
        Testing 3
      </h1>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) queries to make your website responsive.

```
@media (max-width: 760px) {
    .flex {
        flex-direction:column; //change the flex direction from row to column
    }
}
```

Basically, when the screen-size is lower than 760px, you change direction to `column`

Example: ( lower resolution to 760px )

https://jsfiddle.net/972bdkvr/1/